# Question about constructors taking an argument

Tags: constructor

This is my first experience with programming on Ethereum. I'm deploying the sample contract following the instructions shown [here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_deploy.html#a-sample-contract).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract testContract {

    uint256 value;

    constructor (uint256 _p) {
        value = _p;
    }

    function setP(uint256 _n) payable public {
        value = _n;
    }

    function setNP(uint256 _n) public {
        value = _n;
    }

    function get () view public returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how the variable `_p` works here. It shows up as an argument for the constructor. But I did not set it at any point before deployment and do not know how to set it after deployment. I also see that when I call the `get` function, it returns `value` which takes on `_p` due to the constructor.

I have deployed this contract on Ropsten here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xfbad55ee853c127faed5ed30f367e43418226e87.

So what is the uint `_p` and where along the process was it set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployed constructor, which is executed at deployment time, sets value=_p

Comment: Sorry, how is _p set in the first place?

Comment: When the contract is deployed, the code in the constructor is executed, which is the mechanism of smart contracts.
This means that you must construct parameters (if any) during deployment, otherwise the deployment will fail.

Comment: Ah I see - the deployment in Remix was just a click so I guess it did it for me

Comment: Yes.